# R Sort Cleavland Dot Plot by not shown variable

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2

I followed this manual (https://afit-r.github.io/cleveland-dot-plots) to create a Cleaveland Dot Plot which I was able to reproduce but I faced the following challenges:

1. How do I sort my Y-Axis in historical order? The varieties on my y-axis have different release years and although those are not shown in my plot I would like to order them in historical order. Now they are in some wired alphabetic order starting from the back and I don't even know how to change that.
2. I couldn't manage to show the differences between the plots in percentages (like in the manual), could anyone explain to me that in more detail?
3. Do you see any possibility of including the same data for another year?

See below for my code and picture:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
require(dplyr)
require(plotrix)
cleanup = theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(color = "black"))

data19 = read.csv("Harvest_2019_V2.csv", sep = ";")
data19$Experiment_Year <- as.factor(data19$Experiment_Year)
data19$Release_year <- as.factor(data19$Release_year)
Subset2019 = subset(data19, Experiment_Year == 2019)

agHarvest.Weight <- aggregate(Subset2019[, 9], list(Subset2019$Variety,Subset2019$Release_year,Subset2019$Treatment), mean)
agHarvest.Weight$Variety <- agHarvest.Weight$Group.1
agHarvest.Weight$Release_Year <- agHarvest.Weight$Group.2
agHarvest.Weight$Treatment <- agHarvest.Weight$Group.3
agHarvest.Weight$Yield <- agHarvest.Weight$x

right_label <- agHarvest.Weight %>%
  group_by(Variety) %>%
  arrange(desc(Yield)) %>%
  top_n(1)

left_label <- agHarvest.Weight %>%
  group_by(Variety) %>%
  arrange(desc(Yield)) %>%
  slice(2)

ggplot(agHarvest.Weight, aes(Yield, Variety)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Variety)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Treatment), size = 1.5) + 
  geom_text(data = right_label, aes(color = Treatment, label = round(Yield, 0)),
            size = 3, hjust = -.5) +
  geom_text(data = left_label, aes(color = Treatment, label = round(Yield, 0)),
            size = 3, hjust = 1.5) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2500, 4500)) + cleanup + xlab("Yield, g") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","darkgreen"))
```

[image: R Plot Picture]

Comment: Could you post the data or a link to it?

Comment: I am sorry but I can‘t as I don‘t have permission to share the data. Is there any other way you could help me?

Answer (score 1):

OP.  Understandably, you cannot always share data for various reasons.  This is why it is always recommended to either use an existing publicly-available dataset or craft your own in order to produce a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  Fortunately, you're in luck, as I don't mind doing this for you.  :)

TL;DR - there are many ways, but simplest method is to use `reorder(your_variable, variable_to_sort_by)`.  Note that y axis direction goes "bottom-up" rather than "top-to-bottom" on the plot.

#### Example Data

```
df <- data.frame(
  Variety=rep(LETTERS[1:5], each=2),
  Yield=c(265, 285, 458, 964, 152, 202, 428, 499, 800, 900),
  Treatment=rep(c('first','second'), 5),
  Year=rep(c(2000, 2001, 2010, 1999, 1998), each=2)
)

> df
   Variety Yield Treatment Year
1        A   265     first 2000
2        A   285    second 2000
3        B   458     first 2001
4        B   964    second 2001
5        C   152     first 2010
6        C   202    second 2010
7        D   428     first 1999
8        D   499    second 1999
9        E   800     first 1998
10       E   900    second 1998
```

#### Basic Cleveland Dot Plot

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Yield, y=Variety)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=Variety)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Yield), nudge_y=0.2, size=2) +
  theme_bw()
p
```

[image]

#### Sort Variety (Y axis) by Year Column

You should first notice how `ggplot2` arranges your axes.  The key is to understand that the *origin of the plot starts at the bottom left corner*.  This means that the *lowest* value for x and y axes will be at the *left* and *bottom*, respectively.  This is the reason why `df$Variety` is alphabetical, but "goes up" (from bottom to top).  To reverse the y axis, you can just add `scale_y_reverse()` to your plot code, but that only works for continuous axes.  For discrete axes, you can use `scale_y_discrete(limits=rev(df$Variety))`.  You'll see in the following approach we can avoid that.

To sort the y axis by another column, you can use `reorder()` right with the `aes()` call.  The `reorder()` function is basically setup as follows:

`reorder(columnA, column_to_use_to_sort_columnA)`

In this case, you'll want to sort `df$Variety` by `df$Year`, so this should become:

`reorder(Variety, Year)`

...but remember how the y axis "goes up"?  If you want the Y axis to be sorted by `df$Year` and "go down", you can either reverse the axis via `scale_y_discrete(limits=rev(df$Variety))`, or conveniently just sort by `df$Year` in reverse using the syntax:

`reorder(Variety, -Year)`

Putting this together you get this:

```
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Yield, y=reorder(Variety, -Year))) +
  geom_line(aes(group=Variety)) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Yield), nudge_y=0.2, size=2) +
  theme_bw()
p1
```

[image]

You'll see we have our proper order now, where `df$Variety` is sorted by ascending `df$Year`, starting from the top (1999) and going down to the bottom (2010).

#### Other ways?

There's other ways to do your sorting, but I found this most straightforward.  The other fundamentally different approach would be to sort your data frame first, then plot.  However, if you do this, be aware that `ggplot2` will convert any column with discrete values into a *factor* first, and the default factor levels are created by sorting the names in alphabetical order.  This means that if you sort your data frame first, then plot, you'll still be stuck with alphabetical order.  You would need to sort, then discretely convert `df$Variety` into a factor (and specify the levels), then plot.  Something like this works just the same:

```
df <- dplyr::arrange(df, -Year)  # arrange by descending Year
df$Variety <- factor(df$Variety, levels=unique(df$Variety))  # factor and indicate levels

ggplot(df, aes(x=Yield, y=Variety)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=Variety)) +
  geom_point(size=2) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Yield), nudge_y=0.2, size=2) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev(df$Variety))
```

Above code gives you the same plot as the method using `reorder(Variety, -Year)`.

Comment: see my other answer as the comment section was not enough to answer you.

Comment: I see... it seems that without a representative portion of your data it is going to be very difficult to help you much further.  This is something where the solution will come out of understanding how the dataset is organized.  As it stands, we don't have a minimal reproducible example.